# Customise bootstrap buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to have the bootstrap buttons bigger then btn-lg...

heres my current code..

HTML

when i add a new class to the anchor tags classes with padding it makes it look weird..

[image]

but this is what i want it to look like.. (This photo is before the anchor tag was put into the code and its just the  with btn classes. )

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: It didn't add my code when i said "heres my code"

  <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" href="coderesource.html" role="button">HTML</a>

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your post, e.g. a running HTML+CSS code snippet which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tried the same thing but it works without any issue. 
I hope the below code link will help you to understand better.

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.container .btn-outline-success {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  padding: 0 20px;
  min-width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" href="coderesource.html" role="button">HTML</a>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" href="coderesource.html" role="button">CSS</a>
  <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" href="coderesource.html" role="button">Javascript</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me sort it :)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is not the adding any of those classes to the anchor tag, but maybe the containers you are using around the anchors.

I would try to achieve your expected result by using a [flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) and `.justify-content-between` setting inside a row. That way the buttons will have equal horizontal space between them and fill the row. Additional padding can be added for the buttons too with the built-in [padding classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) of Bootstrap 4. (Or you can create custom class width padding too, but don't forget `!important`.) Working example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-between">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success px-5 py-3">HTML</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success px-5 py-3">CSS</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success px-5 py-3">JavaScript</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering its much appreciated